# How do I make my Score timer stop on death?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a bullet hell game where the longer you survive, the more score you get. The score timer starts at 1 and goes up when playing. However, I want it to stop when the player dies, but I can't get it quite right.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScorePerSecond : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    public float scoreAmount;
    public float pointIncreasedPerSecond;
    private string ENEMY_TAG = "Enemy";
    private string FOLLOWENEMY_TAG = "Followenemy";
    private string PLAYER_TAG = "Player";
    private bool isFinished = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        isFinished = true;
        scoreAmount = 0f;
        pointIncreasedPerSecond = 5f;        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isFinished == true)
        { scoreText.text = "Survived time " + (int)scoreAmount;
          scoreAmount += pointIncreasedPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
            isFinished = true;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag(PLAYER_TAG))
            Destroy(gameObject);
        {
            isFinished = false;
        }        
    }   
        //if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag(FOLLOWENEMY_TAG))
        //    Destroy(gameObject);

    

}
```

Comment: i think it's because your isFInished value doesn't change have you checked it ?

Comment: Firstly where exactly do you check for the death of the player? Secondly why are you setting `isFinished` to true after going into an if that requires `isFinished` to be `true`?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavour-like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 1):

So there is a lot of strange things going on in your code!

First of all you probably do not want to set

```
 isFinished = true;
```

right from the beginning. Otherwise you want to change the naming ...

Then note that in

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag(PLAYER_TAG))
        Destroy(gameObject);
    {
        isFinished = false;
    }        
}
```

What you actually do is

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag(PLAYER_TAG))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    isFinished = false;
}
```

so no matter what you collide with you change the state of `isFinished`. You probably rather wanted to make the brackets wrap both lines.

And then checking and setting

```
if(isFinished == true)
{
    ...
    isFinished = true;
}
```

is quite redundant.

And last but not least: You don't need the `isFinished` **at all**!

Since you do

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

this `Update` method anyway will not be executed anymore. So unless there are not multiple instances of this script writing into the same `Text` it should stop as soon as the object was destroyed anyway.

```
public class ScorePerSecond : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string ENEMY_TAG = "Enemy";
    private const string FOLLOWENEMY_TAG = "Followenemy";
    private const string PLAYER_TAG = "Player";

    public Text scoreText;
    public float scoreAmount;
    // Instead of overwriting this hardcoded allow to set it via the Inspector
    public float pointIncreasedPerSecond = 5f;

    private void Start()
    {
        scoreAmount = 0f;      
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // you probably want to increase the value first and then update the display
        // otherwise you always only see the vlaue of the previous frame
        scoreAmount += pointIncreasedPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        scoreText.text = "Survived time " + (int)scoreAmount;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag(PLAYER_TAG))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }        
    } 
}
```

---

What stays quite unclear to me:
Here no player is dying. You rather check if you collide with a player and kill this object itself.

Did you maybe mean to rather do

```
Destroy(other.gameObject);
```

-> In that case, yes you would need the `isFinished` again.

```
public class ScorePerSecond : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string ENEMY_TAG = "Enemy";
    private const string FOLLOWENEMY_TAG = "Followenemy";
    private const string PLAYER_TAG = "Player";

    public Text scoreText;
    public float scoreAmount;
    // Instead of overwriting this hardcoded allow to set it via the Inspector
    public float pointIncreasedPerSecond = 5f;

    private bool isFinished;

    private void Start()
    {
        scoreAmount = 0f;      
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(isFinished) return;

        // you probably want to increase the value first and then update the display
        // otherwise you always only see the vlaue of the previous frame
        scoreAmount += pointIncreasedPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        scoreText.text = "Survived time " + (int)scoreAmount;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag(PLAYER_TAG))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            isFinished = true;
        }        
    } 
}
```